# AngularJS custom directive two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and I am trying to make a custom directive(which has a controller with functions in it) that is linked to a controller. When an object in the controller($scope.MyObj), changes I would like to have a similar object in my directive controller that changes the same way. In addition is it possible to invoke a function/scope method that is declared in my directive controller, from my basic controller(or invoke a function from my directive controller when an object from the basic controller has changed.) ?

Answer (score 0):

Aviv Ben-Yosef writes a pretty nice post about it on http://www.codelord.net where he basically hooks into the controller from a isolated directive scope:

http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/02/controller-directive-communication-part-3-controller-to-directive/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Angular 1.4 and above you can use `bindToController` something like this:

```
.directive('mdAddress', function mdAddress() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        address: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'modules/address/address.html',
      controller: AddressController,
      controllerAs: 'dir'
    };
```